# C#.NET XML Processing via XDocument.Descendants not fetching entities as expected

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml, atom-feed

Using an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338353.aspx) and the [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx) method.

```
//first problem 'entries' doesn't fetch at all
var entries = xmlDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("entry"))
//neither does
//            xmlDoc.Descendants("entry")

var ids = from e in entries 
          select e.Element(XName.Get("id")).Value;
```

The same XDocument code works on a blog feed that's more verbose, i.e. my blog: http://blog.nick.josevski.com/feed/ a snippet is here: http://pastebin.com/KU65dgwL where the 'entry' element is replaced with 'item' and 'id' is replaced with 'link'.

> To test any suggestions I created a [LinqPad code gist](https://gist.github.com/1614853) that demonstrates the issue.

Am I missing something obvious? I've tried various combinations of `.Elements()` `.Elements("entry")` and just `.Descendants()` and then attempting to filter further without luck too.

This is the XML that I'm struggling to extract the entry/id node from:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">Author</title>
    <subtitle type="text">subtitle</subtitle>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.site.com/blog" />
    <entry>
        <id>http://www.site.com/a-blog-post</id>
        <title type="text">Title Of Blog Post</title>

    ...

    <entry>
        <id>http://www.site.com/another-blog-post</id>
        <title type="text">Title Of Another Blog Post</title>
```

Comment: Thanks to ColinE - updated the Gist to include the fix.
https://gist.github.com/1614853

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the XML namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var entries = xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry");
```

Comment: @NickJosevski no problem. It is *such* a common mistake!

Comment: I had tried it via the XName.Get("entry", ns.NamespaceName) but that didn't work.